# Manually download of Xamarin Android Player devices

Tags: android, xamarin

Is there any way to manually download devices for Xamarin Android Player?

For example: I want to download this devices on one machine and install them in Xamarin Android Player on another machine with no internet connection. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The image files for the Xamarin Android player are located in: `C:\ProgramData\XamarinAndroidPlayer\`

You could download the images to another computer and copy those to an USB drive.

You also need:
`C:\Users\Username\.VirtualBox`
and:
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\XamarinAndroidPlayer`

Comment: Ok. So I copied image files from C:\ProgramData\XamarinAndroidPlayer\. What else should I do? What with .vbox files from C:\Users\Username\VirtualBox VM's? How to configure properly VirtualBox settings? 
Should I do anything else to see this copied device in XAP Device Manager?

Comment: Yes you would also need C:\Users\Username\VirtualBox VM's
The settings for those things are saved in some json file inside those directories.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users wishing to locate the same and save time and effort of downloading the same images, you'll find Android Image files located at `/Users/<yourUserName>/Library/XAP` in your OSX partition